# How is this function equivalent to getting the last item in a list?

Tags: haskell

After completing the first problem ("*Find the last element of a list*") in the [99 questions exercises](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/1_to_10), I wanted to see how my solution compared with others and I found [this solution](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/Solutions/1).

```
myLast' = foldr1 (const id)
```

This [documentation](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/foldr1_f.html) seems to show that `foldr1` takes two arguments, the first being a function and the second being a list. But this definition only appears to take a function as an argument. Is there an implicit definition of the arguments passed like this?

```
myLast' xs = foldr1 (const id) xs
```

I have looked up the definitions of `foldr1`, `const`, and `id`, but I'm having a hard time understanding how those three work together to return the last item in the list.

Comment: you will no doubt find in your future Haskell adventures that being able to take advantage of currying is a rather popular Haskell "sport" and an ideal of elegance that many strive to reach.  The concept is known as [Point-free style](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree).  One reason why it's nice is because it allows you to see a function as a **composition** of other functions.  For example, instead of `addAndTimes x = 4 * (2 + x)`, which is a function on x, you can instead say `addAndTimes = (* 4) . (+ 2)`, which is clearly simply a composition of the `(+ 2)` and `(* 4)` functions.

Answer (score 6):

You're exactly right. In Haskell, a function that takes two arguments can actually be treated as a function that takes one argument and returns another function that takes an argument; this is known as [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). Note that the function signature for `foldr1` is:

```
(a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a
```

While we often think of it as "a function that takes a function and a list as arguments and returns a value", it's really "a function that takes a function as an argument and returns a function that takes a list and returns a value".

Answer (score 3):

As mipadi explains, the function is being curried. That explains how the list argument gets there, but perhaps doesn't explain how the actual fold works.

The `const id` bit is a little trixy. `foldr1` is expecting to get something that has the type `a -> a -> a`. The definitions of these functions are

```
const :: x -> y -> x
const x y = x

id :: x -> x
id x = x
```

So, mangling that all together, we have

```
const id =
\ y -> id =
\ y -> \ x -> x =
\ y x -> x
```

In order words, `const id` does the same thing as `flip const`; it's a 2-argument function that throws the first argument away, and returns the second one. It's not terribly obvious that this is so; IMHO, `flip const` would be clearer.

`foldr1` will call this function with the old value as the first argument, and the next list element as the second argument. This function always returns the next list element. The final output from `foldr` is the last output from the function, which will be the last element of the entire list.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that your two examples can be replaced by one another. This can be thought of as algebraic cancelation just like in algebra class.

```
f x y = g x y
```

I can cancel the `y` on each side:

```
f x = g x
```

now I can cancel the x on each side:

```
f = g
```

Take a look a the [wiki page for foldr vs foldl and foldl'](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27) to learn a little more about foldr.

To get an idea of how myLast' works we can do some algebraic suptitution.

```
myLast' [1, 2, 3]

== foldr1 (const id) [1, 2, 3]
```

Now we should use the [definition of `foldr1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-List.html#foldr1) in-particular: `foldr1 f (x:xs) = f x (foldr1 f xs)`

```
== (const id) 1 (foldr1 (const id) [2, 3])
```

`const id` turns out to have the type sig `b -> a -> a` which is the same as `flip const` and it turns out it acts the same as well which is a function that ignores its first argument and returns the second. example: `(const id) 1 3 == 3` *** see below for a little more ***

```
== foldr1 (const id) [2, 3]

== foldr1 (const id) [3]

== 3
```

That last step may not be what you expected but if you check the definition of `foldr1` it contains:

```
foldr1 _ [x] =  x
```

Which pattern matches when their is only one element in the list and returns it.

*** How does `const id` work?

`const` returns its first argument and ignores it second so

```
const id 3   == id

const id 3 4 == id 4 == 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your intuition about functions not needing all their arguments is spot on. And when one function takes another function as a parameter to return another function as a result, it is called "currying." See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying.

(As a side note, this was actually discovered (or rediscovered) by **Haskell Curry**, which is how our Haskell got its name.)

If the idea of currying is still taking time to sink in, this may help:
There are actually two functions defined in `Prelude` called `curry` and `uncurry`. They carry the following types:

```
Prelude> :t curry
curry :: ((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c
Prelude> :t uncurry
uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c
```

`uncurry` takes a 2 argument *curried* function (or a function that takes a function of one argument that returns a function of one argument,) and produces an *uncurrried* function, or a function that takes all of the arguments *all at once* (as a tuple.)

`curry`, as you may imply by the name and by its type, goes the other way, so that it takes a *curried* function (a function that takes all the arguments at once) and produces a function that takes one argument and returns a function that takes the other argument.

Most programming languages work by default in a uncurried fashion, you provide all the arguments and get a result, while Haskell is curried by default.

Now for an example of `uncurry`, we can take a simple function, `(+)`:

```
Prelude> :t (+)
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
Prelude> (+) 1 2
3
Prelude> :t (+)
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
Prelude> :t uncurry (+)
uncurry (+) :: Num c => (c, c) -> c
Prelude> uncurry (+) (1,2)
3
```

And, we could also do this with `const` if we want to:

```
Prelude> :t const
const :: a -> b -> a
Prelude> const 1 2
1
Prelude> :t uncurry const
uncurry const :: (c, b) -> c
Prelude> uncurry const (1,2)
1
```

But having an uncurried version of `const` is just not very useful, because there is no point in having a function that takes two arguments and always returns the first one if you have to specify all the arguments up front.

`const` is useful precisely because it is curried and can be given in a place where a function is needed that takes two arguments and simply returns the first one.

Like in `foldr1`, for example:

```
Prelude> :t foldr1
foldr1 :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a
```

Where the first argument is a curried function of two arguments.
And since the return value of a function can be a function, it can also be so with `const`:

```
Prelude> :t const id
const id :: b -> a -> a
```

`const id` simply takes an argument of any type `b` and returns the `id` function.

So if we can apply `const id` step by step:

```
Prelude> :t const id 1
const id 1 :: a -> a
```

`const id 1` or `const id anyOtherValueHere` just returns the id function.
Which can be used liked so:

```
Prelude> :t const id "Giraffe" 100
const id "Giraffe" 100 :: Num a => a
Prelude> const id "Giraffe" 100
100
Prelude> :t const id (\a b -> undefined) 100
const id (\a b -> undefined) 100 :: Num a => a
Prelude> const id (\a b -> undefined) 100
100
```

So, `const` really ignores its second argument. Directly above, is just like applying `id` to 100.

So, `foldr1 (const id)` simply takes a list and keeps applying `id` to each set of two elements and keeping the second one (because `const id` returns the value of `id` on the second argument passed in) until we have the last element.